# Datatool error: undefined control sequence \begin

Tags: errors, datatool

I'm using `datatool` to make a mail merge.

I have my .csv file.
I've defined my `\DTLloaddb{indirizzi}{/home/kde/Dropbox/edile_150/consulenti_arezzo.csv}`
and if I use `\DTLdisplaydb{indirizzi}`
I have my table printed on the doc.

But if I try to make that:

```
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{indirizzi}{%
\nome=nome, \cognome=cognome,%
\num=num, \via=VIA, \civico=civico, \localita=localita \cap=cap,%
\provincia=provincia, \tel=tel
}
\begin{letter}

%\DTLdisplaydb{indirizzi}

{\nome\ \cognome\\
\via, \civico\ \num\\
\via \civico \localita \\
\cap \provincia \tel}
```

when I make a PDF, I receive this error:

```
undefined control sequence \begin
```

The line number is the same of `\begin{letter}`
and then other errors

```
(Missing control sequence \begin)
```

I can't understand why I receive this error.

Answer (score 5):

There are some errors in your input.

```
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{indirizzi}{%
\nome=nome, \cognome=cognome,%
\num=num, \via=VIA, \civico=civico, \localita=localita, \cap=cap,%
\provincia=provincia, \tel=tel}
{\begin{letter}
  {\nome\ \cognome\\
  \via, \civico\ \num\\
  \via \civico \localita \\
  \cap \provincia \tel}}
```

A comma was missing after `localita`; more important, `\DTLforeach*` requires *three* arguments: the symbolic name of the database, the assignments and the text that must be acted on. With braces around `\begin{letter}{...}` the document should be processed correctly.